# Adding tester and admins to FB app

Tags: facebook, testing

I'm sure this is something blindingly obvious, but I can't work it out.

I've added an admin and a tester user to my app (and I mean they're real people as opposed to the generated random named user that FB offers) but after a couple of weeks they're still listed as '(pending)' and they're unable to login to the web page that I've written using their Facebook account. OAuth responds with an error:

```
Sorry, this feature isn't available right now: An error occurred while processing this request. Please try again later.
```

I appear to be able to login just fine and can test the [currently] limited functions.

Our web page is right at the beginning of development but it's now at the stage where I'd like real people to mess around on the page and give me feedback.

The two users haven't received any messages - I sort of expected they'd get something in their inbox asking to confirm their role with the app.

So how do I go about getting real people to be test users? Have I missed the point of the test user role?

Answer (score 9):

As of this writing (things change), have the Facebook user go to https://developers.facebook.com/requests/

They will need to be logged in to Facebook.

There should be listed one or more pending requests that they will need to confirm. If the Confirm button(s) is disabled, they may need to register as a Facebook Developer before the Confirm buttons are enabled.